# Run OpenCV project in Cloud9

Tags: c++, opencv, cloud9

I have Cloud9(Ubuntu Server) and I installed OpenCV use next command: `sudo apt-get libopencv-*`

But I don't know can or not I run OpenCV project.

Cloud9 has support that?